pins controller uploading duplicates of image rails
I'm stuck uploading 2 copies of each image
i guess im gong to add a way to remove sepearte images but for now how do i stop duplicates?
some help getting through the double vision would help. im almost sure its in the controller
pins controller
class PinsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_pin, only: %i[show edit update destroy upvote downvote]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: %i[index show]
  before_action :authorize_user!, only: %i[edit destroy]

  # GET /pins or /pins.json
  def index
    @pins = Pin.all.order("created_at DESC")
  end

  # GET /pins/1 or /pins/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /pins/new
  def new
    @pin = current_user.pins.build
  end

  # GET /pins/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /pins or /pins.json
  def create
    @pin = current_user.pins.build(pin_params)

    # Ensure that at least one image is attached
    if params[:pin][:images].present?
      params[:pin][:images].each do |image|
        # Ensure image is an actual file
        if image.is_a?(ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile)
          # Read the image content once to calculate checksum
          image_content = image.read
          checksum = Digest::SHA256.hexdigest(image_content)

          # Check if any existing image blob already has this checksum
          unless @pin.images.any? { |img| img.blob.checksum == checksum }
            # Attach image only if it's not already attached
            @pin.images.attach(io: StringIO.new(image_content), filename: image.original_filename, content_type: image.content_type)
          end
        end
      end
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "Please attach at least one image."
      render :new and return
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @pin.save
        format.html { redirect_to @pin, notice: "Pin was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @pin }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @pin.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /pins/1 or /pins/1.json
  def update
    if @pin.user == current_user && @pin.update(pin_params)
      # Reattach new images if provided, avoiding duplicates
      if params[:pin][:images].present?
        params[:pin][:images].each do |image|
          if image.is_a?(ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile)
            # Read the image content once to calculate checksum
            image_content = image.read
            checksum = Digest::SHA256.hexdigest(image_content)

            # Check if any existing image blob already has this checksum
            unless @pin.images.any? { |img| img.blob.checksum == checksum }
              # Attach image only if it's not already attached
              @pin.images.attach(io: StringIO.new(image_content), filename: image.original_filename, content_type: image.content_type)
            end
          end
        end
      end

      redirect_to @pin, notice: "Pin was successfully updated."
    else
      render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # DELETE /pins/1 or /pins/1.json
  def destroy
    if @pin.user == current_user
      @pin.destroy
      redirect_to pins_path, notice: "Pin was successfully destroyed."
    else
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "Not your pin!"
    end
  end

  # Upvote the pin
  def upvote
    if !@pin.votes_for.exists?(voter: current_user)
      @pin.upvote_by current_user
    else
      flash[:alert] = "You have already upvoted this pin."
    end
    redirect_back(fallback_location: pin_path(@pin))
  end

  # Downvote the pin
  def downvote
    if !@pin.votes_against.exists?(voter: current_user)
      @pin.downvote_from current_user
    else
      flash[:alert] = "You have already downvoted this pin."
    end
    redirect_back(fallback_location: pin_path(@pin))
  end

  private

  # Set the pin based on its ID
  def set_pin
    @pin = Pin.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through
  def pin_params
    params.require(:pin).permit(:title, :description, images: [])
  end

  # Authorize user to edit or destroy their own pin
  def authorize_user!
    redirect_to root_path, notice: "Not your pin!" if @pin.user != current_user
  end
end

_pin.erb
<div id="<%= dom_id(pin) %>">
  <div class="grid" data-masonry='{ "itemSelector": ".grid-item", "columnWidth": 200, "gutter": 10 }'>
    <% if pin.images.count == 1 %>
      <div class="single-image-container">
        <%= link_to pin do %>
          <div class="grid-item single-image">
            <p class="text-center text-warning bg-white border border-dark">
              <%= image_tag(pin.images.first.variant(resize_to_limit: [300, 300])) %>
            </p>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    <% else %>
      <% pin.images.each do |image| %>
        <%= link_to pin do %>
          <div class="grid-item">
            <p class="text-center text-warning bg-white border border-dark">
              <%= image_tag(image.variant(resize_to_limit: [300, 300])) %>
            </p>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>


try to create (not build) pin record and then attach images, probably you attach and then rails attaches during save, then try to avoid ask chatgpt anything and mark questions with AI label (there is nothign about AI)

you probably need to remove images from pin_params before passing it to current_user.pins.build(pin_params) <= this will attach images on save plus you're attaching more images manually. this is not needed either StringIO.new(image_content) you already have an image file open: image.

The AI isn't actually helping you here. It's just generating nonsense code.
You do not need to jump through a bunch of hoops to do multiple file uploads with ActiveStorage.
class Pin < ApplicationRecord
  has_many_attached :images
end

class PinsController < ApplicationController
  # ...

  # POST /pins
  def create
    @pin = current_user.pins.new(pin_params)
    if @pin.save
      redirect_to @pin
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  # PATCH /pins/1
  def update
    @pin = current_user.pins.find(params[:id])
    if @pin.update(pin_params)
      redirect_to @pin
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private 

  def pin_params
    params.require(:pin)
          .permit(:foo, :bar, :baz, images: [])
  end
end 

<%= form_with(model: @pin, multipart: true) do |form| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :images %>
    <%= form.file_field :images, multiple: true %>
  </div>
  <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>

That's all thats actually needed. See the guides for ActiveStorage. Start with that and cover it with tests before proceeding. As you can see the controller does NOT need to contain anything except your standard run of the mill CRUD stuff.
If you want to make images "editable" in that users can delete them or upload new images a good way is to create a model that wraps the active storage attachment:
class Pin < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :images
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images
end

class Image < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :pin
  has_one_attached :file
end

You would then use fields_for to create/update the nested records. See Building Complex Forms for an example.
If you want to ensure that the record has at least one image use a validation instead of a guard clause.

AI generating nonsense code? -- but it's AI -- it knows everything. ;)

@dbugger less Skynet and more like Futurama.
